# How to get min-width or similar to work on whole page? IE7 and 8

Tags: html, css

I am creating a Web page, the problem is that when I shrink the window of the browser, the tables and the div will shrink at the size they need to fit the content, and it makes the page look terrible.

I have to declare a width of 90% for all elements, but when I declare min-with:700px; to all elements (div and tables) do not obey and keeps shrinking to fit the content.

Is there anything I am missing? is it IE7 playing arround?

I would appreciate any help to fix this issue (with no JavaScript if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min-width` doesn't work right in IE. Have a look at [this article](http://blog.throbs.net/2006/11/17/IE7+And+MinWidth+.aspx) for some help with this issue. There are two hacks there of differing complexity.

Another [discussion of this topic here](http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/96081).